# Why is clang over-complicating my simple factorial function?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, compiler-optimization, clang++

Consider a simple factorial function:

```
static int factorial(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return factorial(argc);
}
```

Compiling with `-O2` yields a very interesting difference:

- **g++ 7.3**: I get virtually the same loop structure converted into assembly with 10-ish instructions.
- **clang++ 5.0.0**: I get a huge mess of 220+ instructions and I have no idea what is going on.

[See the comparison here (Compiler explorer)](https://godbolt.org/g/eDQYmS)

Building locally and comparing runtimes, the simple g++ binary definitely runs faster for all values within reason (i.e. that don't cause overflow) on Ubuntu 17.10.

**Can anyone tell me *why* clang is going to all this trouble, and *what* it's trying to do (and failing in both size and speed)?**

Comment: Auto-vectorizer gone berserk.

Comment: @user463035818 Obviously I can't tell for *all* cases, but running locally the clang binary was 2-3x slower.

Comment: try adding the option `-ftree-vectorize` to gcc's command line. clang is just assuming you wanted vectorisation

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, adding `-ftree-vectorize` to g++ yields more instructions (still about half compared to clang) and makes no difference to `clang`. I'd love to be find a reference to *how* it's planning to vectorize this though

Comment: Running the code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70d0e863189c8d99) clang is faster. (benchmark might not be the greatest)

Comment: If you want Clang to produce code similar to that from gcc, use `-Os` instead of `-O2`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hard-coding the value allows the compiler to optimize a lot more though

Comment: I knew I did something wrong.  After switching to a volatile input gcc is faster: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd545b6980d5c159

Comment: Interestingly, gcc is still faster with -ftree-vectorize

Comment: OT: I wondered about the fact that `factorial()` is called with `argc`. I don't say it's wrong - just remarkable. It makes it a little bit harder to start the app. with too big input (which might cause an `int` overflow or even a stack overflow). ;-)

Comment: At the first glance, it seems to be impossible to parallelize code which consists of recursive function calls. Considering that modern compilers might be able to detect tail-recursion (what would be appropriate for `factorial()`) and to resolve this to iteration followed by loop un-rolling it becomes imaginable (at least to me). For me (as human), it would be obvious that n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * ... * 2 * 1 can be grouped to solve sub-expressions separately and hence possibly concurrently. The impressive fact (for me) is when compilers start to "see this".

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone tell me why clang is going to all this trouble, and what it's trying to do (and failing in both size and speed)?

It's trying to minimise the number of test-and-branch operations by vectorising the code.

It's certainly failing on size. As for whether it's failing on speed, have you bench-marked it?

gcc will do the same if you add the command line option `-ftree-vectorize`.

Comment: Do you know any good resource for reading about vectorization strategies for this (in my limited experience) seemingly un-vectorizable problem?

Comment: "have you bench-marked it?" Yes, and the clang version is 2-3x slower on my machine (Ubuntu 17.10). This was confirmed by another user in the comments to my original post. Even if I compile gcc with `-ftree-vectorize`, clang is still significantly slower.

Comment: @naslundx Thanks for the info. clang overtook gcc for a while, but it seems the old king is back :)

Comment: @naslundx I had another look. clang reverts to the small solution if you use the `-Os` option

Comment: @naslundx: **clang enables auto-vectorization at `-O2`, but gcc only with `-O3`**, not `gcc -O2`.  If you want full optimization, you should use `-O3` (except in cases where the compiler shoots itself in the foot).  In those cases (or in general), use profile-guided optimization so the compiler knows that typical args are small.  Hopefully it will then figure out it's not worth going berserk with vectorization.  (IDK if it's ever faster to vectorize even for large inputs which overflow; if not then it's a compiler missed-optimization bug which should be reported.)